Why concatenation can't handle Nones in categorical columns when the DF can hold it in the first place
I have 2 DFs with object type columns, which work fine with concatenation.
Code
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'], 'B': ['B0', None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5'], 'B': [None, None]})

print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DFs")
print(df1)
print(df2)

print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DTypes")
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.dtypes)

Corresponding Output
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DFs
    A     B
0  A0    B0
1  A1  None
    A     B
0  A4  None
1  A5  None
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DTypes
A    object
B    object
dtype: object
A    object
B    object
dtype: object
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Concatenation 1 - No Warning
    A     B
0  A0    B0
1  A1  None
0  A4  None
1  A5  None

But if I do the same with categorical columns, I get a FutureWarning
Code with Categorical data type
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Categorical DTypes")
df1 = df1.astype('category')
df2 = df2.astype('category')
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.dtypes)

print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Concatenation 2 - Gives warning")
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))

Corresponding Output
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Categorical DTypes
A    category
B    category
dtype: object
A    category
B    category
dtype: object
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Concatenation 2 - Gives warning
bla.py:37: FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or all-NA entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty or all-NA columns when determining the result dtypes. To retain the old behavior, exclude the relevant entries before the concat operation.
  print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
    A    B
0  A0   B0
1  A1  NaN
0  A4  NaN
1  A5  NaN

df2 had a NaN to start with and there is no problem with it, but when I try to concatenate with all NaN columns, I get the warning. The suggestion is to remove such entries altogether. Why is this the case? Why does concatenation seem to have issues with NaNs?
Here is the full code
import pandas as pd


def bla():
    '''The main function, that can also be called fromother scripts as an API'''

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'], 'B': ['B0', None]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5'], 'B': [None, None]})

    print(pd.__version__)

    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DFs")
    print(df1)
    print(df2)

    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Original DTypes")
    print(df1.dtypes)
    print(df2.dtypes)

    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Concatenation 1 - No Warning")
    print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))

    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Categorical DTypes")
    df1 = df1.astype('category')
    df2 = df2.astype('category')
    print(df1.dtypes)
    print(df2.dtypes)

    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Concatenation 2 - Gives warning")
    print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bla()

PS: Pandas version is 2.2.2

can you provide print(pd.__version__)?

Pandas version is 2.2.2, edited question

This behavior was initially described here (see issue 43507 in Sept. 2021), and was later reverted back (issue 47372 in June 2022).
In your first case you have an object dtype for both B columns, thus the common dtype after concat is unchanged.
To give an easier to understand example, combining a datetime64 and float column would force the float to become datetime64:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"bar": [pd.Timestamp("2013-01-01")]}, index=range(1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"bar": np.nan}, index=range(1, 2))
res = pd.concat([df1, df2])

         bar
0 2013-01-01
1        NaT  # NaN was converted to NaT

This used to convert the column to object, now this raises a warning. I think the behavior is expected to change in pandas 3.0.
Regarding categoricals, what matters in your case is that you have different categories. If you set common categories, (even with all None); then there won't be a warning:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                    'B': pd.Categorical(['B0', None], categories=['B0'])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5'],
                    'B': pd.Categorical([None, None], categories=['B0'])})

pd.concat([df1, df2])


Even in my second case, dtype of both B columns is 'categorical' (though the categories themselves are different)

@Krishna that's the issue with categoricals, if you had the same categories (even with all None) there wouldn't be a warning (see update).

This is workable, let me try it thanks @mozway
